# Read a specific column from any type of file

Tags: java, file-io

How can I read any type of file from a location and access only a particular column to perform some operations on it. Some rows in my column may contain null values too.
Here's an example:

```
name | age | sex
xyz  | 22  | F
yyy  | 25  | M
zzz  |     | F
aaa  | 22  | M
```

I want to access the column `age` so that I can perform some operations on it, like calculate age group, or performing some other task(s). I have written the code for this function but I still need to access the column to perform this.
I'm pretty new at file reading, hence I need help. I need to do this in java.

I have tried the following:

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line+"line ?????");
    String[] cols = line.split("|");
    System.out.println("lets see column only=="+cols[2]);
}
```

Yet my output is only the 2nd character of the 1st column.

Comment: i hav tried 
 while (s.hasNextLine()) {
           String line = s.nextLine();
           System.out.println(line+"line ?????");
             String[] cols = line.split("|");
             System.out.println("lets see column only=="+cols[2]);

         }
and yet my output is only the 2 character of the 1st column

Comment: also if my 1st row contains data "xyz|zzz"|22|F then '|' seperator will be read 4 times. thus how will i escape this if it is inside double quotes ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***I have tried***
>
> ```
> ...
>     String[] cols = line.split("|"); 
> ...
> ```

This doesn't work since `split` takes a regular expression, and **`|` is a special character** when interpreted as a regular expression.

Instead, try

```
String[] cols = line.split("\\|");
                            ^^
```

Comment: thank you this works.Now if i want to skip n number of rows because they are the header . Here only 1.

Comment: Add `for (int i = 0; i < linesToSkip; i++) s.nextLine();` or something similar.

Comment: thank you this also works fine . the seperator '|' needs to be preceeded by '\\' however if i have a tab delimited file \t works fine. Hence if the file changes my code needs modifications i.e. if i take the file seperator as input from the user it wont work for both cases . IS there a solution for this?

Comment: Yes. Would you mind pasting that as a new question? (it's kind of a new question, and it would be better to post the answer as an answer and not a comment.) Paste a link here and I'll answer your new question right away.

Comment: I already answered :) but that's a different question. The question in your comment above, was how to escape the regular expression used in the split, so that it works for user-specified delimiters.

Comment: Updated my answer. That should clear things up. You should remember to accept (checkmark) answers that resolve your issues.